# how to fetch respose data by retrofit with multiple parameters By GET Request in Jetpack compose

Tags: php, android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

**In these days i am building An english learning app for beginners
so i have problem, i want to fetch response data with two parameters (level and unit)
from database as shown in php code by retrofit Like this,**

**https://adeega.xisaabso.online/Api/Article_vocabulary.php?Level=1&Unit=1**

**so how can i do it? I need help to do that?
Here is my Code Below**

**Vocabulary_Api.kt**

```
const val Vocabulary = "https://adeega.xisaabso.online/Api/"

interface getVocabularies {
   @GET("Article_vocabulary.php")
   fun getVocabularies(): Call<Vocabularies>
}

object getVocabulariesInstance {
   val getVocabulariesSections: getVocabularies

   init {
      val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
         .baseUrl(Vocabulary)
         .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
         .build()
      getVocabulariesSections = retrofit.create(getVocabularies::class.java)
   }
}
```

**Vocabulary.kt**

```
  val users = getVocabulariesInstance.getVocabulariesSections.getVocabularies()

  val data = remember { mutableStateOf(Vocabularies()) }
  users.enqueue(object: Callback<Vocabularies> {
     override fun onResponse(
        call: Call<Vocabularies>,
        response: Response<Vocabularies>
     ) {
        val userData = response.body()
        if(userData != null) {
           data.value = userData
        }
     }
     override fun onFailure(call: Call<Vocabularies>, t: Throwable) {
        Toast.makeText(context, t.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
     }
  })


  LazyColumn(
     contentPadding = PaddingValues(
        horizontal = 12.dp,
        /*vertical = 0.dp*/
     ),
     verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(10.dp)
  ) {
     items(data.value) { item ->
        Cards_Vocabulary(data = item, navController)
        //Divider(color = Color.Gray, thickness = 1.dp)
     }
  } // END LazyColumn
```

**database.php**

```
if(!empty($_GET['Level']) && !empty($_GET['Unit'])) {

    $Level = (int)$_GET['Level'];
    $Unit  = (int)$_GET['Unit'];


    $Article = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM App_vocabularies 
                                WHERE LevelID = ? AND UnitID = ?");
    $Article->bindParam(1, $Level);
    $Article->bindParam(2, $Unit);
    $Article->execute();
    $Article = $Article->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
        echo json_encode($Article);

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to know how to pass parameters as queryString to a query, here is what to do

```
interface getVocabularies {
    @GET("Article_vocabulary.php")
    fun getVocabularies(@Query("Level") level: Int, @Query("Unit") unit: Int): Call<Vocabularies>
}
```

**Vocabulary.kt**

`getVocabulariesInstance.getVocabulariesSections.getVocabularies(aLevel, anUnit)`

Or if you want to avoid multiple function parameters and pass all at once

```
interface getVocabularies {
    @GET("Article_vocabulary.php")
    fun getVocabularies(@QueryMap queries: Map<String, String>): Call<Vocabularies>
}
```

**Vocabulary.kt**

```
val params : MutableMap<String, String> = mutableMapOf()
params["Level"] = aLevel
params["Unit"] = anUnit

getVocabulariesInstance.getVocabulariesSections.getVocabularies(params.toImmutableMap())
```

Comment: but my app shows message (java.io.EOFException: end of input at line 1 and path 1 $)

Comment: this error occurs when the json response that your server returns does not cmatch to the object that you put as a response in the code. for example your server returns an array of elements and instead of putting a `List<T>` in response you put a simple `T`. Which is in your case, you must do this 
`fun getVocabularies(): Call<List<Vocabularies>>`

Comment: `fun getVocabularies(): Call<List<Vocabularies>>`

Comment: fun getVocabularies(
      @Query("Level") level: String,
      @Query("Unit") unit: String
   ): Call<List<Vocabularies>>

Comment: val data = remember { mutableStateOf(Vocabularies()) }
      users.enqueue(object: Callback<List<Vocabularies>> {
         override fun onResponse(
            call: Call<List<Vocabularies>>,
            response: Response<List<Vocabularies>>
         ) {
            val userData = response.body()
            if(userData != null) {
               data.value = userData
            }
         }
         override fun onFailure(call: Call<List<Vocabularies>>, t: Throwable) {
            Toast.makeText(context, t.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
         }
      })

Comment: i have this error after updating code (Type mismatch: inferred type is List<Vocabularies>? but Vocabularies was expected)

Comment: You must share your entire code so that I can better help you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248809/discussion-between-mohammed-and-logancodemaker).